# Cannot create or connect to local Mongo DB with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a mongo DB database with node js. I have installed MongoDB community server 4.4 in my computer. I can do CRUD operations directly from the console. But when I try to connect it to my app It does not work. There is no error message in the console. My code as follows.

```js
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

[This is my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbstI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `mongoose.connect()` like below :

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully connected to database.");
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I added this to my code. But There was no error. So I reinstalled everything(node, MongoDB, etc). Now It's working. I don't understand what was the exact error. Now It's solved. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As per your question your code looks fine and on console i don't see any error but as you are saying your database is not connecting you can put your code in try catch method

```
 try {
  mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB", {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true})
    console.log( "Database Connected Successfully")
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
   
}
```

it will show you the error

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. everything is ok now. I reinstalled the node and Mongo DB again. It seems like the error was not in the code. It was something else.

Answer (score 0):

try this
Create a database called "mydb":

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: I couldn't find an error. Then I reinstalled Node and Mongo DB. Then the problem solved. I have no Idea What was the exact error. But Thank you for the help.